# Accessing the image which is in external bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I created a bundle with name applausible.bundle, i placed the bundle in supporting files.This is my code

```
NSBundle* myBundle;
myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Library/applausible.bundle"];
NSString *path = [myBundle pathForResource:@"splash.png" ofType:nil];
[imageName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:path]];
```

Here I am unable to display the image on the image view. Another way I tried like this I place the image on the image view using xib,while running the app. The output is coming like this in console
Could not load the "splash_screen high resolution.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.xxxxxxx.ImageSample". Can any one tell me where i made a mistake.Finally my goal is to display the image on the `UIImageview` which is in external bundle.

Comment: Please format your question in readable format.

Comment: Put log stmt next to
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"applausible" ofType:@"Bundle"]; and next to your image path....

Comment: bundle path is displaying perfectly but image path is null

Comment: image path is also coming but the image is not dsplaying

Comment: did you initialize the image view and you allocated memory for it.

Comment: @chiller i gave path to the image directly thats why i didn't get the output.Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: If my ans helps you out try to upvote. or add comment on my ans for next time improved ans

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may help you.

```
    NSString bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"applausible" ofType:@"Bundle"];
NSLog(@"Bundle path is %@",bundlePath);
NSBundle myBundle;
myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
NSString *path = [myBundle pathForResource:@"splash_screen high resolution" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
[imageName setImage:image];
```

please try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"applausible" ofType:@"Bundle"];
```

using this method you can get the bundle path.Then use your code from second line

```
myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
NSString *path = [myBundle pathForResource:@"splash" ofType:n@"png"];
[imageName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:path]];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for giving response. I tried that one what you mentioned above but it is not getting the result.